# Java: Is there an exception for when a user enters a number out of range

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

Outside of the context of an Array index, is there any exception in Java that can be thrown when the user enters a number outside the range asked for by a program?

ie. The program wants an integer between 0-100 and user enters 132, could an exception be thrown manually or does it have to be custom?

EDIT: I get that it doesn't make sense to use an exception for this, it's for an assignment and I want to know my options. Easy on the hair trigger down voters.

Comment: A user should never have to deal with exceptions, Just display an error message and ask for another number.

Comment: As I know there is no "NumberOutOfRangeException" in standars Java.

Comment: You may reuse exceptions in the Java API as long as they make sense (v.g., if the number will be an index you may use `IndexOutOfBoundsException`). And in fact, you may create your own custom exceptions extending those, if needed. Anyway, @Keppil is right; use exceptions only for communication between method calls *inside* the program; the user should get a nice, readable & informative message.

Comment: Actually my teacher emailed me back and said java wouldn't consider it an exception unless I threw one. I don't know if that means make one or not.

EDIT: The teacher said to throw an exception in the first place, I don't get it either.

Comment: It means that Java has no built-in method to say "if user input is not between X and Y", throw exception. You have to take user input, parse it and check its values; and create and throw the exception when needed.

Answer (score 10):

You can throw IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 1):

If you particularly want to use exception handling for this then you should probably define your own custom exception for it rather than reuse a standard Java one. That way you can be certain you are only catching your particular case. If you do define an exception you will need to manually throw it and catch it.

Note that I am referring here specifically to an exception related to user entry that you wish to handle. Java has an excellent set of exceptions for handling errors that are internal to your code (e.g. null pointer exceptions).

Having said that this does not seem like a good use case for an exception. Your code should consider every value a user might enter as within normal use. Exception handling is best reserved for handling things that are exceptions to normal operations.

Comment: I completely disagree; if a method that expects a non-null value gets a null value, my method will throw a `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException` and not a `MyExceptionThatMeansExactlyTheSameThanNpeException`

Comment: @SJuan76 My comment was about a value entered by a user, not a value sent into a method. I'm not proposing customer exceptions for things Java already has exceptions for.

Comment: @SJuan76 I added a clarification to make the clearer.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Language Specification, regarding Integer Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) says:

The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any way.

An integer operator can throw an exception (§11) for the following reasons:

- Any integer operator can throw a `NullPointerException` if unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) of a null reference is required.
- The integer divide operator / (§15.17.2) and the integer remainder operator % (§15.17.3) can throw an `ArithmeticException` if the right-hand operand is zero.
- The increment and decrement operators ++ (§15.14.2, §15.15.1) and -- (§15.14.3, §15.15.2) can throw an `OutOfMemoryError` if boxing conversion (§5.1.7) is required and there is not sufficient memory available to perform the conversion.

I m not a fan of "exception driven architecture",  ;)

Implement a check if the integer is over 100 and return an error, status code, etc as feedback for user/system etc.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are expensive. Should use some cheap test function or make a wrapper class that accepts only the range you want and carries an "error" variable through all calculations to the end. You check that error at end, trace it back to the source. Traveling error makes it possible to see multiple errors at the same time, not just stuck at the first error happened.

```
public class IntegerWithError
{
    int result;
    int error;
    int errorSource; 
    // some methods to check for range, alter "error" as needed.
    // some methods to sign the start point of error

}


private static IntegerWithError Test(int parameter)  
{
    IntegerWithError iwe=new IntegerWithError();
    if(parameter>5)
    {
        iwe.error=1;
        iwe.errorSource=iwe.hashCode();
    }
    iwe.result=parameter;

    return iwe;

}

 ....
 ParameterWithError p1,p2;
 ....
 MatrixMultiplyWithError(p1,p2);
 RenderWithErrors(p1,p2,b1,b1);
 TraceError(p1); // finds if it was a function, a constructor or something.
```